# Django heroku connection refused

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, heroku

Deployment of my site to heroku seems to be working, until I try to use my login feature then it throws an error:

OperationalError at /login/ could not connect to server: Connection refused 
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

This error seems to occur during template rendering of a form (captcha).

my procfile:

```
web: waitress-serve --port=$PORT capstonenotespool.wsgi:application
```

settings.py:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = { 'default': dj_database_url.config() }

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'capstonenotespool',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': '****',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

I've tried changing $PORT in the procile to 5432, but this does not work. I've also tried manually setting the PORT in settings to 5432 but this also doesn't work.

I also noted that Django error logs produces these variables:

```
SERVER_NAME 'localhost'
SERVER_PORT '23994'
SERVER_PROTOCOL 'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE 'waitress'
```

Removing the localhost from HOST in settings gives the following error:

could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: I didn't know heroku db can run on localhost - are you sure?..

Comment: removing localhost gives the error at the bottom of the post (edited).

Comment: because removing hostname leads to using socket - so the question is the same - does heroku db run your your local  machine over unix socket?.. I'm not good in heroku, but I thought it is hosting company, so you have to define THEIR ip in configs

Comment: I got it working, Found the heroku db settings i needed to use. Cheers!

Comment: sure. put the detailed answer please to help others